# Retrieving Graph Data using JSON and API data for Android App

Tags: java, android, json, api, kotlin

I am trying to create an Android mobile app primarily in Kotlin to track Covid-19 data. I am using retrofit to retrieve the API data. However when running the application to test my data come up blank. For some reason the API data is not being retrieved. The site I'm using is CovidActNow.org which requires an API key.

I call the base URL in my MainActivity file with:

```
private const val BASE_URL = "https://api.covidactnow.org/v2/"
```

and then I've also created a Kotlin file called CovidData which contains:

```
package com.example.covid19tracker

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import java.util.*


data class CovidData(
    @SerializedName("date") val date: Date,
    @SerializedName("positiveTests") val positiveTests: Int,
    @SerializedName("negativeTests") val negativeTests: Int,
    @SerializedName("newDeaths") val newDeaths: Int,
    @SerializedName("state") val state: String

)
```

and Services which should be getting the data with:

```
package com.example.covid19tracker

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface Services {
    @GET("country/US.json?apiKey={myAPIkeywithoutbrackets}")
    fun getNationalData(): Call<List<CovidData>>

    @GET("states.json?apiKey={myAPIkeywithoutbrackets}")
    fun getStatesData(): Call<List<CovidData>>
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm just calling the API key incorrectly or if I have a typo, but I would appreciate any feedback or help!!

My response code for national data is:

```
{"fips": "0", "country": "US", "state": null, "county": null, "level": "country", "lat": null, "locationId": "iso1:us", "long": null, "population": 331486822, "metrics": {"testPositivityRatio": 0.242, "testPositivityRatioDetails": {"source": "other"}, "caseDensity": 132.5, "contactTracerCapacityRatio": null, "infectionRate": 0.8, "infectionRateCI90": 0.1, "icuCapacityRatio": 0.8, "vaccinationsInitiatedRatio": 0.755, "vaccinationsCompletedRatio": 0.639, "vaccinationsAdditionalDoseRatio": 0.266}, "riskLevels": {"overall": 5, "testPositivityRatio": 3, "caseDensity": 5, "contactTracerCapacityRatio": 4, "infectionRate": 0, "icuCapacityRatio": 1}, "cdcTransmissionLevel": 3, "actuals": {"cases": 75285898, "deaths": 889522, "positiveTests": 70042418, "negativeTests": 684690203, "contactTracers": 66210, "hospitalBeds": {"capacity": 686316, "currentUsageTotal": 526948, "currentUsageCovid": 125691}, "icuBeds": {"capacity": 78639, "currentUsageTotal": 63033, "currentUsageCovid": 22118}, "newCases": 295374, "newDeaths": 3579, "vaccinesDistributed": 667094365, "vaccinationsInitiated": 250184240, "vaccinationsCompleted": 211954555, "vaccinationsAdditionalDose": 88286037, "vaccinesAdministered": 539921122, "vaccinesAdministeredDemographics": null, "vaccinationsInitiatedDemographics": null}, "annotations": {"cases": {"sources": [{"type": "NYTimes", "url": "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data", "name": "The New York Times"}], "anomalies": []}, "deaths": {"sources": [{"type": "NYTimes", "url": "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data", "name": "The New York Times"}], "anomalies": []}, "positiveTests": null, "negativeTests": null, "contactTracers": null, "hospitalBeds": null, "icuBeds": null, "newCases": null, "newDeaths": {"sources": [], "anomalies": [{"date": "2020-06-25", "type": "zscore_outlier", "original_observation": 2466.0}]}, "vaccinesDistributed": {"sources": [{"type": "other", "url": "https://data.cdc.gov/Vaccinations/COVID-19-Vaccinations-in-the-United-States-Jurisdi/unsk-b7fc", "name": "Centers for Disease Control and Prevention"}], "anomalies": []}, "vaccinationsInitiated": {"sources": [{"type": "other", "url": "https://data.cdc.gov/Vaccinations/COVID-19-Vaccinations-in-the-United-States-Jurisdi/unsk-b7fc", "name": "Centers for Disease Control and Prevention"}], "anomalies": []}, "vaccinationsCompleted": {"sources": [{"type": "other", "url": "https://data.cdc.gov/Vaccinations/COVID-19-Vaccinations-in-the-United-States-Jurisdi/unsk-b7fc", "name": "Centers for Disease Control and Prevention"}], "anomalies": []}, "vaccinationsAdditionalDose": {"sources": [{"type": "other", "url": "https://data.cdc.gov/Vaccinations/COVID-19-Vaccinations-in-the-United-States-Jurisdi/unsk-b7fc", "name": "Centers for Disease Control and Prevention"}], "anomalies": []}, "vaccinesAdministered": {"sources": [{"type": "other", "url": "https://data.cdc.gov/Vaccinations/COVID-19-Vaccinations-in-the-United-States-Jurisdi/unsk-b7fc", "name": "Centers for Disease Control and Prevention"}], "anomalies": []}, "testPositivityRatio": null, "caseDensity": {"sources": [{"type": "NYTimes", "url": "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data", "name": "The New York Times"}], "anomalies": []}, "contactTracerCapacityRatio": null, "infectionRate": {"sources": [{"type": "NYTimes", "url": "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data", "name": "The New York Times"}], "anomalies": []}, "infectionRateCI90": {"sources": [{"type": "NYTimes", "url": "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data", "name": "The New York Times"}], "anomalies": []}, "icuCapacityRatio": null, "vaccinationsInitiatedRatio": null, "vaccinationsCompletedRatio": null, "vaccinationsAdditionalDoseRatio": null}, "lastUpdatedDate": "2022-02-02", "url": null}
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the attached API URL > `https://api.covidactnow.org/v2/`

If you're using the below API
`https://apidocs.covidactnow.org/api/#tag/County-Data/paths/~1county~1{fips}.json?apiKey={apiKey}/get`

I think you didn't map the class attributes with Json data correctly.

So please, try to make sure you mapped the data returned from the API matched with the Data class you're using to map JSON data to it.

Please, try the below class I think it will work for you.

```
@Parcelize
data class CovidData(
        @SerializedName("state") val state: String,
        @SerializedName("lastUpdatedDate") val date: Date,
        @SerializedName("actuals") val actuals: ActualData,

): Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class ActualData(
        @SerializedName("positiveTests") val positiveTests: Int,
        @SerializedName("negativeTests") val negativeTests: Int,
        @SerializedName("newDeaths") val newDeaths: Int
)
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the response code and body you are receiving after making the request?

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! It wouldn't let me paste the response code because it was too long so I edited it into my question, but when I enter the API manually it pulls the data fine and I double checked my variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the:-
1:- Base URL is pointing to the correct API
2:- country/US.json?apiKey={myAPIkeywithoutbrackets} is returning the list of the CovidData
3:- Change your object into this:-

```
package com.example.covid19tracker

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import java.util.*

@Parcelize
data class CovidData(
    @SerializedName("date") val date: Date,
    @SerializedName("positiveTests") val positiveTests: Int,
    @SerializedName("negativeTests") val negativeTests: Int,
    @SerializedName("newDeaths") val newDeaths: Int,
    @SerializedName("state") val state: String
): Parcelable
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I made sure that the Base URL second and my get are pointing to the correct API. When combined, they return the values fine. And I changed my object, but unfortunately still no luck.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "change my object". A change to ?